# Parse ISO 8601 date-time in format YYYY-MM-DDTHH-MM-SSZ

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

I have a large dataframe with time stamps that look like this:

```
"2019-05-15T01:42:15.072Z"
```

It resembles a [ISO 8601 combined date and time representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations).

How can I parse this string into a real date-time format?

The characters (`T` and `Z`) inside the data seems to make it difficult.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply parse the timestamp by specifying the format in `as.POSIXct` (or `strptime`)

```
as.POSIXct("2019-05-15T01:42:15.072Z", format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OSZ", tz = "UTC")
#[1] "2019-05-15 01:42:15 UTC"
```

Explanation:

`%Y`, `%m` and `%d` denote the year (with century), month and day; `%H`, `%M` and `%OS` denote the hours, minutes and seconds (including milliseconds). The `T` and `Z` are simply added to the `format` string, because

> Any character in the format string not part of a conversion specification is interpreted literally

See `?strptime` for the different conversion specifications.

### A comment on timezones

As the `Z` denotes UTC times, we have manually added `tz = "UTC"` to `as.POSIXct` (as pointed out by @BennyJobigan). If you wanted the timestamp to be converted to your local (target) timezone, you can do

```r
# In timezone of target, i.e. convert from UTC to local
lubridate::with_tz(
    as.POSIXct("2019-05-15T01:42:15.072Z", format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OSZ", tz = "UTC"),
    tz = Sys.timezone())
# [1] "2019-05-15 11:42:15 AEST"
```

(Obviously the output depends on your local timezone and might be different from what I get.)

Comment: That works, thanks for your help. How can I apply this over the whole dataframe?

Comment: `as.POSIXct` is vectorised, so you can do something like `df$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(df$timestamp, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OSZ")` (assuming `df` is your `data.frame` with column `timestamp`); or use `transform` as in `df <- transform(df, timestamp = as.POSIXct(timestamp, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OSZ"))`

Comment: Isn't the timezone messed up? The original data was in UTC (denoted by the 'Z' timezone offset), but it was parsed into local time (AEST zone) without an adjustment to the actual time. I think `as.POSIXlt(mytimestamp, format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OSZ", tz="UTC")` would be more appropriate.

Comment: You are right @BennyJobigan; I'll make an edit. Anecdotally, things are often not as clear. I used to work with SCADA data that had UTC-like timestamps, even though times corresponded to AEST. Based on my experience, date-time data are almost always messy, in particular if they come from different systems & software.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Yes, dealing with timezone, DST, and formatting is certainly high on the list of things that makes one want to rip out their hair!